# Date Time Error when applying UDF in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Trying to convert the string month in a pyspark dataframe into a  month number using a User Defined Function with datetime library.

[image]

But there is an error when running the function.

I created the below function and applied it as follows:

```
import datetime 
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
def convert_datetime(month_name): 
  print(month_name)
  """This function is to create string month into correct numerical form"""
  datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, "%B")
  month_number = datetime_object.month
  return month_number

numericalCaseUDF = udf(lambda x:convert_datetime(x),IntegerType())
```

```
date_listing.withColumn("Month",col("Month").cast('string'))
print(date_listing.schema)
date_listing.dropna().show(truncate=False)
date_listing.select(f.col("month"),numericalCaseUDF(f.col("month"))).show(truncate=False)
```

But i encounter the below error, I am not sure where the error is. Would anyone be able to help?

[image]

Comment: Print out the value of the month which is causing the error. It seems the value the udf is receiving is incorrect or badly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use UDFs for things which are already available in pyspark functions. UDFs should be last resort as they are very slow. Here's an example to achieve without using python UDF.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F



sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
["29 September 2022 20:00:00"],
["02 July 2019 19:00:00"],

      ]

df1Columns = ["date_col"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_parsed = df1.withColumn("parsed_date_column", F.to_timestamp(F.col("date_col"), "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
print("parsed dataframe")
df1_parsed.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_parsed = df1_parsed.withColumn("month_number", F.month(F.col("parsed_date_column")))
print("month extracted dataframe")
df1_parsed.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+--------------------------+
|date_col                  |
+--------------------------+
|29 September 2022 20:00:00|
|02 July 2019 19:00:00     |
+--------------------------+

parsed dataframe
+--------------------------+-------------------+
|date_col                  |parsed_date_column |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
|29 September 2022 20:00:00|2022-09-29 20:00:00|
|02 July 2019 19:00:00     |2019-07-02 19:00:00|
+--------------------------+-------------------+

month extracted dataframe
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+
|date_col                  |parsed_date_column |month_number|
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+
|29 September 2022 20:00:00|2022-09-29 20:00:00|9           |
|02 July 2019 19:00:00     |2019-07-02 19:00:00|7           |
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------+
```